# webmethod returning whole html instread string value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, xmlhttprequest, webmethod

I am trying to call asp.net webmethod from xmlhttp object.

My webmethod is like this

```
[WebMethod]
public string getCities(string province)
```

And my javascript is like following

```
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest({mozSystem: true});
 xmlhttp.open("POST","http://www.rental-1.com/lp.aspx/getCities/Ontario",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
alert(xmlhttp.readyState+", "+xmlhttp.status);
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
var v1=xmlhttp.responseText;
alert(v1);
}}
```

In response I am getting the whole html of the page. But above I am calling just webmethod and I expecting string value in return.

Any help will be appreciated. Why I am not getting just string value instead of html of the page

here is my server side code

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<string> getCities(string province)
{

    List<string> strp = new List<string>();



            strp=getCitiesFromDB(province);

    return strp;
}
```

Comment: @Quentin actually if u just read the question u will find out it not the same.

Comment: @Quentin I changed the title

Comment: Your change to the question doesn't make any sense. You make a request to the URL. You get the body of the response in a string. Since that URL gives you an HTML document you get a complete HTML document in the string.

Comment: @Quentin Yes that is the question. How can I call webmethod from xmlhttp object

Comment: You appear to be doing that already. The web method just isn't doing what you want it to do. That isn't a problem with the JavaScript.

Comment: @Quentin if you know can u please answer it how can I call webmethod and get just return value of webmethod. I am kind of confused

Comment: You should probably include more than 2 lines of your server side code if you want anyone to tell what is wrong with it.

Comment: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/ might be relevent.

Comment: @Quentin ok I updated my code. added server side getCities method.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET will only invoke your web method if you use a post request (which you are) and send any parameters to the server as JSON (which you aren't). When those requirements aren't met, ASP.NET will just treat your request as a normal one to the underlying ASPX page. That's why you're seeing the full page's HTML returned.

If you `JSON.stringify({ province: 'Ontario' })`, set a content type header of `application/json`, and send that as your POST data, you should get a JSON array back from ASP.NET instead of the full page's HTML.

See the last section of this post for the specifics: http://encosia.com/asmx-and-json-common-mistakes-and-misconceptions/

Comment: I am calling  a method with parameter "province" which is string. My question is what will my url be. should it be rental-1.com/lp.aspx?op=getCities?v. v is json object. But it is not working

Comment: @user4545762: A URL like lp.aspx/getCities is okay, but the JSON object needs to be sent as the request's POST data, not on the querystring.

Comment: can you show me how to do it in request's POST data?

Comment: @user4545762: I don't have a raw XMLHttpRequest sample handy, but it would be `$.ajax('lp.aspx/getCities', { type: 'post', contentType: 'application/json', data: JSON.stringify({ province: 'Ontario' }), success: function(response) { console.log(response); } });` using jQuery's `$.ajax`.

Comment: I am looking for javascript solution and not jquery. can you please let me know the pure javascript solution. Just tell me how can I embed parameter info in post data

Comment: @user4545762: It's been so long since I've used XMLHttpRequest by hand, I don't remember the exact syntax. You might want to put that in a separate question. It will work once you make your request like I've explained in the answer above. This question is probably a good start (but make sure you don't use that Content-Type): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/sending-post-data-with-a-xmlhttprequest